# How to replace atomikos in distributed transaction in spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, distributed-transactions

I try to follow migration guide when atomikos was removed in spring boot 3:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide

but I can no see information about it. Other frameworks like [narayana](https://github.com/snowdrop/narayana-spring-boot/issues/95) or bitronix is also not in spring boot dependencies.

Comment: The fact that it isn't in the dependencies doesn't mean you cannot use it.

Comment: what do you mean ? I dont want to mix jakarta in new spring boot 3 vs javax in this old dependencies

Comment: Narayana has a Jakarta based implementation afaik whic you can use (manual configuration required) with Spring Boot. Which is what i meant, the fact that Sprng Boot doesn't provide management for something automatically doesn't mean it cannot be used. If it implements the proper interfaces you can add manual configuration.

Comment: There is now a `transactions-spring-boot3-starter` see also: https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/ReleasesCategory.

Answer (score 1):

Spring had direct support for distributed transaction tools like Atomikos in the past. However, starting from Spring 3, this support has been discontinued, as indicated in the Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide. You can use followıng dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
   <artifactId>transactions-spring-boot3-starter</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
   <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can look at [here](https://github.com/ahmetuygun/xa-demo) for full code and article.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of the Spring Boot team, Atomikos now includes its own starter project for spring boot - supporting both JakartaEE *and* "good old" javax EE.

Just check [the atomikos website](https://www.atomikos.com) for the latest.