# Spring boot 3 with Atomikos

Tags: spring-boot, jta, distributed-transactions, atomikos, spring-boot-3

Spring Boot 3 doesn't support Atomikos.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide

Support for the following dependencies has been removed in Spring Boot 3.0:
Apache ActiveMQ
**Atomikos**
EhCache 2
Hazelcast 3

Atomikos published Spring Boot 3 starter module.
https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/ExtremeTransactions6dot0

```
 <dependency>
         <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
         <artifactId>transactions-spring-boot3-starter</artifactId>
         <version>6.0.109</version>
 </dependency>
```

Can anyone guide me to write a Atomikos configuration to support transaction for JMS and JPA.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a guide online that describes the steps and includes also a github sample project.

See link: [Article distrubuted-transactions-springboot-3-atomikos](https://medium.com/@ygnhmt/distrubuted-transactions-springboot-3-atomikos-a5adfcba2c41)
Github: [Github](https://github.com/ahmetuygun/xa-demo)

It uses the transaction essentials which is the open source version of Atomikos.

Also see similar articles here:[Atomikos MultiDB Transactions](https://medium.com/swlh/atomikos-multi-db-transaction-system-c16168df22e5) ,[atomikos-multi-db-transaction-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949411/how-to-replace-atomikos-in-distributed-transaction-in-spring-boot-3) and here [A Guide to Atomikos](https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomikos)

Here is the Official Page of Atomikos that refers to the pom dependencies for spring boot 3: [Atomikos official page](https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/ExtremeTransactions6dot0)

In summary here are the steps to follow:

1. Add the **dependencies** in the pom:

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
>    <artifactId>transactions-spring-boot3-starter</artifactId>
>    <version>6.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
>    <version>1.1</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. Create Beans for **JpaVendorAdapter**, **UserTransaction**, **TransactionManager** and **PlatformTransactionManager**.
3. Define the **ConnectionFactory** JMS for XA.
4. Define the **Datasource** for XA
5. Also define a **jta.properties** file inside the resources folder of your spring boot application to specify the settings of Atomikos you prefer.
   All the available properties are described here:
   [Atomikos properties](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties)
   Also they have already default values.

The initialisation properties are resolved with this order: [Property Value Lookup](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/PropertyValueLookup)

During the start up of your spring boot application you should see a welcome message from Atomikos in the logs and the list of all the properties with their values.

The approach above overrides the default Spring transaction manager with one provided by Atomikos (UserTransactionManager).

Also the official guide of Atomikos describes which options you have to use:
6.0.109 is the Commercial version "Extreme Transactions", for open source use version 6.0.0 "Transactions Essentials".
I would suggest you to read the [Release Notes](https://www.atomikos.com/Main/ReleaseNotes) to know what is supported from Atomikos.

And in general if your application is J2EE use [J2eeUserTransaction](https://www.atomikos.com/downloads/transactions-essentials/com/atomikos/AtomikosTransactionsEssentials/javadoc/3.7/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/J2eeUserTransaction.html) and [J2eeTransactionManager](https://www.atomikos.com/downloads/transactions-essentials/com/atomikos/AtomikosTransactionsEssentials/javadoc/3.7/com/atomikos/icatch/jta/J2eeTransactionManager.html).

I think with the above approach the transactions are controlled by the UserTransaction which set the boundaries.

As a continuation it would be useful to check if we can use Atomikos without accessing the UserTransactions, so to expect spring boot container to be able to handle the transactions by itself.
And using only these spring boot transaction properties: [Spring boot transaction properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.transaction)